# How do I implode a json object to a string in php?

Tags: php, json

I have this json held in a variable that I am trying to convert to a string?

```
$json_object = '[{"125":"1"},{"126":"2"},{"127":"3"},{"128":"4"},{"129":"5"},{"130":"6"},{"131":"7"},{"132":"8"},{"133":"9"},{"134":"10"},{"135":"11"}]';
```

What I want as my end result is something that looks like this:

```
$json_object1 = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11';
$json_object2 = '125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135';
```

Is there a way we can modify the `implode(",",$json_object)` function to achieve this?

Another question:
Any idea how we might put this

```
{"26":"Child - 1500.00","28":"Foreigner - 4000.00","27":"Resident - 3000.00"}
```

To a list like

```
26 : Child - 1500.00
27: Resident - 3000.00
28: Foreigner - 4000.00
```

Comment: Decode the JSON into an array, extract the values and keys of each object in the array into a new array. Don't think at the level of string modification.

Comment: There is no such thing as a json object.... it is all a string until you decode it to object or array

Comment: [`JSON`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) **is** string.

Comment: @axiac I know that. Do you understand what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @nick do **you** understand what you are trying to achieve? (*"I have this json held in a variable that I am trying to convert to a string?"*)

Comment: `implode(",",$json_object)` fails. It expects an array as its second argument.

Comment: @nick read about [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). Use all of them to get the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$json_object = '[{"125":"1"},{"126":"2"},{"127":"3"},{"128":"4"},{"129":"5"},{"130":"6"},{"131":"7"},{"132":"8"},{"133":"9"},{"134":"10"},{"135":"11"}]';

$json = json_decode($json_object);
echo implode(", ", array_map(function($obj) { foreach ($obj as $p => $v) { return $p;} }, $json));
echo "<br>";
echo implode(", ", array_map(function($obj) { foreach ($obj as $p => $v) { return $v;} }, $json));
```

See https://3v4l.org/p3p45

Comment: any idea how we might put this  `{"26":"Child - 1500.00","28":"Foreigner - 4000.00","27":"Resident - 3000.00"}` to a list like `26 : Child -  1500.00 <br/>28: Foreigner - 4000.00<br/> 27: Resident - 3000.00`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php

$jsonString = '[{"125":"1"},{"126":"2"},{"127":"3"},{"128":"4"},{"129":"5"},{"130":"6"},{"131":"7"},{"132":"8"},{"133":"9"},{"134":"10"},{"135":"11"}]';

$decoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$keys = [];
$values = [];

foreach($decoded as $item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        $keys[] = $key;
        $values[] = $value;
    }
}

$resultStringKeys = implode(",", $keys);
$resultStringValues = implode(",", $values);

var_dump($resultStringKeys, $resultStringValues);
```

The output:

```
string(43) "125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135"
string(23) "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$json_object = '[{"125":"1"},{"126":"2"},{"127":"3"},{"128":"4"},{"129":"5"},{"130":"6"},{"131":"7"},{"132":"8"},{"133":"9"},{"134":"10"},{"135":"11"}]';
$arr1 = []; $arr2=[];
$jsonobj = json_decode($json_object);
foreach ($jsonobj as $val){
    $Arrval = (array) $val;
    foreach ($Arrval as $k=>$v){
        $arr1[]=$k;     
        $arr2[]=$v;
    }
}
$json_object1 = implode(",",$arr1);

$json_object2 = implode(",",$arr2);
```

Out put is

```
125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution (not the best if the size of your JSON input is measured in MBs but good enough for several KBs of input):

```
$input = '[{"125":"1"},{"126":"2"},{"127":"3"},{"128":"4"},{"129":"5"},{"130":"6"},{"131":"7"},{"132":"8"},{"133":"9"},{"134":"10"},{"135":"11"}]';

// Decode the JSON into arrays; TRUE as the second argument requires arrays, not objects
$data = json_decode($input, TRUE);

// Run through the list, extract the data into a new list
$output = array_reduce(
    $data,
    function(array $carry, array $item) {
        // Put the keys and values of $item into the corresponding lists on $carry
        $carry['keys'] = array_merge($carry['keys'], array_keys($item));
        $carry['vals'] = array_merge($carry['vals'], array_values($item));
        return $carry;
    },
    // Start with empty lists of keys and values
    array('keys' => array(), 'vals' => array())
);

// That's all; $output['keys'] contains the keys, $output['values'] contains the values.    
echo('Keys: '. implode(',', $output['keys'])."\n");
echo('Values: '.implode(',', $output['vals'])."\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

first convert json data to php array then store all key and value in different array then implode it

```
<?php
$json_object = '[{"125":"1"},{"126":"2"},{"127":"3"},{"128":"4"},{"129":"5"},{"130":"6"},{"131":"7"},{"132":"8"},{"133":"9"},{"134":"10"},{"135":"11"}]';
$array_data = json_decode($json_object, true);

foreach($array_data as $data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $array_key[] = $key;
        $array_value[] = $value;
    }
}

$final_key = implode(",", $array_key);
$final_value = implode(",", $array_value);
echo $final_key;
echo "<br>";
echo $final_value;
```

then output is :

```
125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Comment: That's… half an answer…

Comment: ok  check my update answer , i mistake to read full question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this,

```
$json_object = '[{"125":"1"},{"126":"2"},{"127":"3"},{"128":"4"},{"129":"5"},{"130":"6"},{"131":"7"},{"132":"8"},{"133":"9"},{"134":"10"},{"135":"11"}]';

    $key_arr = array();
    $val_arr = array();

$json_arr = json_decode($json_object);

    foreach($json_arr  as $val)
    {

        foreach($val as $key => $value)
        {
            $key_arr[] = $key;
            $val_arr[] = $value;
        }
    }

$resultStringKeys = implode(",", $key_arr);
$resultStringValues = implode(",", $val_arr);
```

And echo your `$resultStringKeys` and `$resultStringValues` and you will get your output.

Comment: Now this will work.

Comment: who is downvoting this? This works perfectly!!

Comment: yes, it works perfectly and easy to understand..thanks...