# How to turn get the value of json format to array

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.
I query dates from this query:

```
 $data = DB::table('itemregistrations')
         ->select('itemregistrations.dd', 'itemregistrations.mm', 'itemregistrations.yy')
         ->where('itemregistrations.itemregistrationid', $id)
         ->get();
```

I want to get the value to put in an array so that i can implode the array into string. I cannot implode it in this format.

```
dd($data);
```

produce this:

```
Collection {#521 ▼
#items: array:1 [▼
0 => {#515 ▼
  +"dd": 15
  +"mm": "0"
  +"yy": 2007
  }
 ]
}
```

How to turn this result to:

```
 0 => {15, 0, 2007}
```

Thank you

Comment: You really have to show some code: what are you variables calles etc.
`Array.prototype.slice.apply(Object.values({"dd": 15, "mm":"0", "yy": 2007})).map((el) => parseInt(el))`

Answer (score 1):

why don't you convert the collection to an array using toArray() method and then simply do the json_encode on the array you got.
later on you can even pass it in your response.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps other..

I find solution guided by those comments from this question here:

[How do I implode a json object to a string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215171/how-do-i-implode-a-json-object-to-a-string-in-php)

I modify my code:

```
  //query tarikh masuk                    
   $datatarikh = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                ->select('itemregistrations.dd', 'itemregistrations.mm', 'itemregistrations.yy')
                ->where('itemregistrations.itemregistrationid', $id)
                ->get();

    //**************** format the value of the date************************                      
    $data = json_decode($datatarikh, true); 

    $val_arr = array();

    foreach($data  as $val)
    {
        foreach($val as $key => $value)
        {
             $val_arr[] = $value;
        }
    }

    $result = implode("-", $val_arr);
```

It changes associative array to indexed array to be imploded. Thanks for your input.

From an array:

```
 array:1 [▼
 0 => array:3 [▼
"pdrm_dd" => 15
"pdrm_mm" => "01"
"pdrm_yy" => 2007
 ]
]
```

The output result:

```
 "15-01-2007"
```